# Google Sign-In returns unknown error if the user cancels on the permissions page

Tags: ios, google-signin

I'm using Google Sign-In on iOS.  The login flow will show (at least) two views.  First, the user is prompted for email & password.  On the second, the user is prompted to accept some permissions, like "View your email address" and "View your basic profile info".

If the user hits cancel on the first view, the didSignInForUser callback gets the expected error code, that the user cancelled.

However, if the user hits cancel on the second view, when prompted for permissions, the didSignInForUser callback gets an unknown error.  Specifically, code -1 and the localized description is "Unknown error".

Is that expected?  And if so, is there a good way to detect that this unknown error is in fact a known error, that the user hit cancel?

Comment: Which SDK are you using? The 2.0.1 SDK has some changes / improvements in the callback errors. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios

Comment: I'll try 2.0.1 & report back.

Comment: Same unknown error in 2.0.1 and 2.1.0.

Comment: Rascal is right. Let me file a feature request with the team and see if we can get back a better error code during that second part of the sign-in process.